# Solve $(x^2-2018^2)^2 - 8072x - 1 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I already know the answer using WolframAlpha, however, I don't know how to tackle this by hand.
I've tried using the difference of squares on the first term, didn't get much though, I tried using $x^2-2018^2 = \sqrt{8072x+1}$, but I didn't know how to continue without squaring again, and I've noticed $8072 = 4 \cdot 2018$.

Comment: Hint: $8072=4 \cdot 2018$.

Comment: They already said that in their question @Mindlack

Comment: My mistake. So, other hint: try to complete $1+8072x$ into a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get $$ \left(x^2 + n^2 \right)^2 - \left(2nx+1 \right)^2 = (x^2 - n^2)^2 - 4nx-1 $$

Once written as a difference of squares, note that $A^2 - B^2 = 0$  means $(A+B)(A-B) = 0,$ so that  $A+B=0$  or $A-B = 0,$  possibly both.

Here  $$ n = 2018 $$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

$$(x^2-2018^2)^2=8072 x+1$$

$$(x-2018)^2(x+2018)^2=4\times 2018 x+1$$

A:

$ \begin{cases}(x-2018)^2=4\times 2018 x+1 \\ (x+2018)^2=1\end {cases}$

$x=-2019$ and $x=-2017$ which are the solution of $(x+2018)^2=1$  can be solutions of this system if they suffice the first equation. This gives a family of solutions.

B:

$ \begin{cases}(x+2018)^2=4\times 2018 x+1 \\ (x-2018)^2=1\end {cases}$

Similarly this system can  gives another family of solutions.

Comment: How do u know that A and B are only possible ways to factor $4 \times 2018x +1$?

Comment: @eatfood, It is not only way of factorization. another type is in other answer.You can also construct other system of equations and try to search other possible solutions. I gave an Idea or hint for this type of equations.

Comment: @HassanAshraf, Oh, I thought you want solutions in $ \mathbb Z$.